# Is it possible to use 2 prompt that ask a user for data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to ask a user for both name and a question with a prompt() method, but when I try to add 2 prompt() methods, one for name and the other for the question, I get this error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') when trying to output that.

But if I remove the username prompt(), the code work perfectly

```js
const userName = prompt("What is your name?", "Victor");
let userQuestion = prompt("Enter a question", "Can I sleep with my Boss?");
userName.length > 1 ? document.getElementById("8ball").innerHTML = "Hello " + userName + "!" : document.getElementById("8ball").innerHTML = "Hello!";

document.getElementById("ballQ").innerHTML = userName + " " + userQuestion;
```

```html
 <div id="8ball"><p id="ballQ"></p>
        <div id="8BallResult"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You would typically use a ternary as follows: `document.getElementById("8ball").innerHTML = (userName.length > 1) ? "fred" : "ginger"`

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the `prompt`?  It looks like you're trying to write to a nonexistent DOM node (`#8ball` when the DOM contains `#8BallResult`)

Comment: Another possibility: `prompt` returns `null` when there's no user input, and null does not have a length.  You don't really want the length anyway, you're just checking truthiness, so `userName ? foo : bar` would work just as well.

Comment: @DanielBeck #8ball is in the DOM it is actually the first div

Comment: Aaaaaah. I see; that's the root node, so when you write over its innerHTML you wipe out the other nodes you're trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The line with the ternary overwrites the innerHTML of `#8ball`.  That removes `#ballQ` and `#8BallResult` from the DOM, because they are children of that node; later you get an error when you try to write to `#ballQ` which no longer exists.
2. `prompt` doesn't always return a string; if there's no user input it returns `null`, and trying to check the `.length` of `null` will throw an error.

Below I rearranged your HTML to prevent wiping out DOM nodes you're trying to keep, and changed the `.length` check against userName to be a simple truthiness check (since all you're really looking for is whether the name exists).

I also rearranged things to make the code easier to read -- all those repeated document.getElementById calls were kind of obscuring what you were trying to do.

```js
let userName = prompt("What is your name?", "Victor");
let userQuestion = prompt("Enter a question", "Can I sleep with my Boss?");

let nodeOne = document.getElementById("8ball");
let nodeTwo = document.getElementById("ballQ");

nodeOne.innerHTML = (userName) ?
  "Hello " + userName + "!" :
  "Hello!";

nodeTwo.innerHTML = userName + " " + userQuestion;
```

```html
<div id="8ball"></div>
<p id="ballQ"></p>
<div id="8BallResult"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved my problem and I learn a new thing, I was using the logic that I can add to the HTML but yet still have the other nodes that are inside not knowing that the insert innerHTML will wipe the other nodes.

Comment: Happy to help!  If you need to write to a DOM node but don't want to overwrite its existing children you'd be wanting [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or similar

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

When setting the innerHTML of an element, that does not exist, it'll return null.

You're basically setting a property of null, which is giving you the error.

Make sure that your code comes after the selected element.

Try the following code.

###### HTML

```html
<div id="8ball">
  <p id="ballU"></p>
  <p id="ballQ"></p>
  <div id="8BallResult"></div>
</div>
```

###### JavaScript

```js
const userEl = document.getElementById("ballU");
const questionEl = document.getElementById("ballQ");

const userName = prompt("What is your name?", "Victor");
const userQuestion = prompt("Enter a question", "Can I sleep with my Boss?");

userEl.innerHTML = userName ? Hello ${userName}!: Hello!;
if (userQuestion) questionEl.innerHTML = ${userName} ${userQuestion};
```

Comment: Hello @jsx-clan thanks for your reply but it just doesn't work at all, now I have another error that, expected : but saw ? probably because you use the ternary operator wrongly